# C# : is there an appropriate collection for fast range-related search?

Tags: c#, algorithm, range

I have data like that:

| Time(seconds from start) | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 2 |
| 16 | 4 |
| 19 | 2 |
| 25 | 9 |

There are a lot of entries (10000+), and I need a way to find fast enough sum of any time range, like sum of range 16-25 seconds (which would be 4+2+9=15). This data will be dynamically changed many times (always adding new entries at the bottom of list).

I am thinking about using sorted list + binary search to determinate positions and just make sum of values, but is can took too much time to calculate it. Is there are any more appropriate way to do so? Nuget packets or algorithm references would be appreciated.

Comment: store sorted in list, use List.BinarySearch to find first element, then walk till you get last

Comment: Yes, I thought about that - but it seems like there are could be something more efficient (by example if range is whole data set, then you still will need to make 10000+iterations)

Comment: Some idea - to pre-calculate LODs for data. By example split it first for each 1000 seconds, then for each 100, then for each 10, then for each second. And then just modify these collection when new data pops up, and for answering you can just check which ranges it overlaps, and return data from pre-calculated lods.

Comment: there are no iterations here. just one search then walk.

Comment: How about precalculating cumulative sums?

Comment: "there are no iterations here. just one search then walk." I mean you will have to go from first element to last one, giving 10000+ operations of sum

Comment: "How about precalculating cumulative sums?" - yes, probably this is the way. I am wondering is there are any existed solutions for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate cumulative sum:

```
Time Value CumulativeSum
15   2     2
16   4     6
19   2     8
25   9     17
```

Then for range [16,25] it will be task to binary search left border of **16** and **25** exact, which turns into 17 - 2 = 15

Complexity: **O(log(n))**, where **n** - size of the list.

Binary search implementation for lower/upper bound can be found in my repo - https://github.com/eocron/Algorithm/blob/master/Algorithm/Sorted/BinarySearchExtensions.cs